# Start learning laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to learn php framework, laravel. I have installed laravel 5.2 on my computer but I don't know how can I start to explore it. So, is there any recommended website for me to learn laravel framework?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[laracasts.com](http://www.laracasts.com)

Laravel's official website has plenty of tutorials, and a great community able to help you.

Comment: Is it free? Because I'm still a university student and I don't have enough money :)